# Programmatically added UIView to a UIScrollView does not catch UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm developing an app with Swift 4 and targeting iOS 9 and above. For a view I have establish a UIScrollView as in the following post:

https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7

So my test app looks like this:

[Storyboard status corresponds to the final step of the link above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhNLH.png)

My project is cocoapods based so I added FlexLayout and PinLayout libraries for custom layout my UIView. I added custom UIViews programmatically inside the view container of the scrollview (like cards) and for each UIView when they are instantiated I attach a UITapGestureRecognizer to such instance.

ViewController:

```
func drawRows() {
    flexContainer.flex.direction(.column).define {
        (mainFlex) in
        for i in 0..<15 {
            let newCard = EmptyCard(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
            newCard.backgroundColor = .lightGray
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 50))
            label.text = "Card: \(i)"
            newCard.addSubview(label)
            mainFlex.addItem(newCard).marginLeft(10).marginBottom(5).width(200).height(100)
        }
    }
    contentView.addSubview(flexContainer)
    flexContainer.pin.all()
    flexContainer.flex.layout(mode: .adjustHeight)
    scrollView.contentSize = flexContainer.frame.size
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    drawRows()
}
```

Each card has the next class definition:

```
import UIKit

class EmptyCard: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addGestureToCard()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addGestureToCard()
    }

    func addGestureToCard() {
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleOnTap))
        gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    @objc func handleOnTap(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Hola Mundo")
    }
}
```

The result is the following:

[resulting UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAVyE.png)

The problem comes when I tap on a UIView that is not showed at first sight because it was added in a coordinate of the UIScrollView that is far from the device dimensions, for example the cards 6 and above the tap gesture recognizer doesn't work

[cards that don't have the gesture recognizer active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTHjG.png)

For the rest of the UIViews (the ones that fit initially within the device dimensions, i.e., Card 0, Card 1, Card 2, Card 3, Card 4 and the top of Card 5) the gesture recognizer works perfectly, i.e., the "Hola Mundo" string message is shown in the debug console. I tried to fix the problem giving fixed dimensions to the view container (the one inside of the scroll view) but that did't work. I hope that somebody has a clue for this scenario, thank's in advance.

Comment: You are going to need to provide code of what you have tried so far and explain more clearly exactly what part you want help with.

Comment: At the risk of being unhelpful, have you looked into using a UICollectionView for this task? Judging by your description, this would seem to be the tool for the job.

Comment: Try to enabled the `userInteraction` of added view to `true`.

Comment: far from the device dimensions ? can you please show Expected Output and tried code

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'll elaborate on the question

Comment: Hi @MikeS159 I already updated my question

Comment: @iOSGeek I updated my question with code and screeshoots of the output, thanks in advance

Comment: @pkc456 thanks, I already set userInteractionEnabled to true and it works but only for the cases I describe in the question.